# curl и отправка данных

Tags: c, curl

Есть такие массивы:

```
url[] = "http://example.com/a?b=c&d=e";
data[] = "query=test";
```

При этом

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
```

срабатывает нормально.

А мне нужно, чтобы `query=` не было в data, то есть:

```
url[] = "http://example.com/a?b=c&d=e&query=";
data[] = "test";
```

Но тогда `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data)` не срабатывает.

Есть ли опции, с которыми такое сработает?

Можно, конечно, в отдельном массиве объединить url и data через strcat, но хотелось бы без этого обойтись.